# Recreating Microbots Scene

Tags: particles

I'm trying to imitate this scene from big hero where he uses a lot of microbots to form a bigger shape.
[image]

I think I'll have to use a particle system with the microbots as an object and have a model of the thing I want the microbots to take the shape of but I can't get any further than that. Can someone tell me how it's done?
Thanks

Comment: My answer here might help you... https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274508/what-is-the-best-way-to-naturally-animate-hundreds-objects/274527?noredirect=1#comment471233_274527

Comment: It did, thank you